# How to check a key is in dictionary which store in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, find

demo code

```
lst = [{'foo':1}, {'bar':2}]
```

===================

```
'foo' in lst
```

return False as the key is inside the dictionary which need to explicitly use

```
'foo' in lst[0]
```

Is there a way to return boolean but without giving the magic number?
for loop is not under consideration if the list is many and it gives troubles to append for not exist key as dictionary.

Comment: Why not to use regular python dictionary? Or you just got the result from an API, and don't  want to use extra memory?

Comment: *"for loop is not under consideration if the list is many"*.Using loop is effective enough when giving a list of dict.Or you need to change the construct of your `lst`.

Comment: @Yz what do you mean regular python dictionary?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA say that if the list was increasing time by time, first I need to for loop check for an existing list, then I need to for loop again to retrieve the index number, although I didn't need that yet I just though that is not a good practice, maybe there is some way to do better than this, correct me if I'm wrong, I appreciated for new knowledge.

Comment: `O(n)` is not bad.If you use only one dict, it would be `O(1)`.

Comment: @nelLuffy Why not to store the data in this way `data = { 'foo': 1, 'bar': 2 }`?

Comment: @Yz to output the content to CSV format, basically I want to output a list of information stores in the dictionary with fields specify, so if you have a suggestion it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No loops and no "magic number"...

```
lst = [{'foo':1}, {'bar':2}]
foo, bar = lst
'foo' in foo
```

Output:

```
True
```

Or you could use a recursive function, no loop or "magic number" here either:

```
def find_foo(lst, n=0):
    if n > len(lst) - 1:
        return False
    if 'foo' in lst[n]:
        return True
    return find_foo(lst, n+1)

print(find_foo([{'foo': 1}, {'bar': 2}]))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: I realize that my question does not so detail, but your answer gave me the sense to solve my problems, this answer well qualifies for the solution.